# Add a covariate as an additional independent variable, an interaction, or a random intercept?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression

I am trying to decide whether to add a covariate as either an additional independent variable, an interaction, or a random intercept (using a binned version). **EDIT**: To be clear, I'm not looking for "the answer." I'm wondering what tests I should be using, or what metrics to compare, to make a decision.

In my model, my goal is to find how dialogue acts (DAs) affect typing speed. But I know that different word-count by itself affects typing speed, and so I want to control for it. I don't want my results to just reflect the effect of word-count.

Word-count alone affects speed:

```
Call:
lm(formula = speed ~ word_count, data = dat)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2809 -0.6323 -0.0313  0.5981  5.4843 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.035317   0.024250   1.456   0.1454  
word_count  -0.003150   0.001659  -1.899   0.0577 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.954 on 4106 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0008771, Adjusted R-squared:  0.0006337 
F-statistic: 3.604 on 1 and 4106 DF,  p-value: 0.0577
```

DAs have distinct word-counts:

```
Call:
lm(formula = word_count ~ DA, data = dat, contrasts = list(DA = contr.sum))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-12.732  -5.528  -2.461   2.840 128.539 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   9.9841     0.4071  24.523  < 2e-16 ***
DA1           1.1758     0.5795   2.029   0.0425 *  
DA2          -2.4183     0.9673  -2.500   0.0125 *  
DA3          -1.3507     1.4547  -0.929   0.3532    
DA4          -2.3591     1.6136  -1.462   0.1438    
DA5           2.7480     0.4393   6.256 4.36e-10 ***
DA6           2.1826     1.6136   1.353   0.1762    
DA7           1.4772     0.4864   3.037   0.0024 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 8.833 on 4100 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03234,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03069 
F-statistic: 19.58 on 7 and 4100 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Predicting speed using only `DA` as a predictor gives me the following results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = speed ~ DA, data = dat, contrasts = list(DA = contr.sum))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4507 -0.6297 -0.0472  0.5859  5.5306 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.09433    0.04367  -2.160  0.03084 * 
DA1         -0.15474    0.06216  -2.489  0.01284 * 
DA2          0.10535    0.10376   1.015  0.31000   
DA3          0.39258    0.15604   2.516  0.01191 * 
DA4         -0.29078    0.17308  -1.680  0.09304 . 
DA5          0.06760    0.04712   1.435  0.15145   
DA6         -0.53485    0.17308  -3.090  0.00201 **
DA7          0.14679    0.05218   2.813  0.00492 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9474 on 4100 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01605,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01437 
F-statistic: 9.551 on 7 and 4100 DF,  p-value: 8.015e-12
```

Predicting speed using `DA` and `word_count` as predictors gives me the following results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = speed ~ DA + word_count, data = dat, contrasts = list(DA = contr.sum))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4477 -0.6314 -0.0425  0.5914  5.5145 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) -0.073486   0.046762  -1.572  0.11614   
DA1         -0.152282   0.062190  -2.449  0.01438 * 
DA2          0.100300   0.103828   0.966  0.33409   
DA3          0.389763   0.156043   2.498  0.01254 * 
DA4         -0.295702   0.173116  -1.708  0.08769 . 
DA5          0.073340   0.047342   1.549  0.12142   
DA6         -0.530292   0.173110  -3.063  0.00220 **
DA7          0.149878   0.052230   2.870  0.00413 **
word_count  -0.002087   0.001675  -1.246  0.21277   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9474 on 4099 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01642,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.0145 
F-statistic: 8.552 on 8 and 4099 DF,  p-value: 1.283e-11
```

Predicting speed using `DA`, `word_count`, and their interaction as predictors gives me the following results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = speed ~ DA * word_count, data = dat, 
    contrasts = list(DA = contr.sum))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4338 -0.6280 -0.0410  0.5856  5.5058 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -0.200869   0.074694  -2.689  0.00719 ** 
DA1            -0.255582   0.098818  -2.586  0.00973 ** 
DA2             0.308548   0.173661   1.777  0.07569 .  
DA3             0.240487   0.348955   0.689  0.49076    
DA4            -0.836703   0.275878  -3.033  0.00244 ** 
DA5             0.215011   0.080550   2.669  0.00763 ** 
DA6            -0.499081   0.227272  -2.196  0.02815 *  
DA7             0.354291   0.087419   4.053 5.15e-05 ***
word_count      0.012949   0.007150   1.811  0.07021 .  
DA1:word_count  0.005635   0.008314   0.678  0.49797    
DA2:word_count -0.025724   0.018076  -1.423  0.15479    
DA3:word_count  0.017009   0.036206   0.470  0.63853    
DA4:word_count  0.072621   0.028015   2.592  0.00957 ** 
DA5:word_count -0.016158   0.007403  -2.183  0.02912 *  
DA6:word_count -0.007132   0.013194  -0.541  0.58888    
DA7:word_count -0.021757   0.007788  -2.794  0.00524 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9444 on 4092 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02428,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.0207 
F-statistic: 6.788 on 15 and 4092 DF,  p-value: 9.455e-15
```

Predicting speed using `DA` as a fixed effect, and `word_count` broken into quintiles as a random effect gives me the following results:

```
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use
  Satterthwaite's method [lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: speed ~ DA + (1 | word_count_quantile)
   Data: dat

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 11226.3  11289.5  -5603.1  11206.3     4098 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.6462 -0.6652 -0.0492  0.6190  5.8393 

Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
 word_count_quantile (Intercept) 8.709e-05 0.009332
 Residual                        8.958e-01 0.946456
Number of obs: 4108, groups:  word_count_quantile, 5

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   -0.09454    0.04385  253.38241  -2.156  0.03200 * 
DA1           -0.15418    0.06211 4098.12757  -2.482  0.01309 * 
DA2            0.10514    0.10366 4095.62130   1.014  0.31054   
DA3            0.39162    0.15590 4097.34693   2.512  0.01204 * 
DA4           -0.29040    0.17292 4103.91379  -1.679  0.09316 . 
DA5            0.06808    0.04711 2986.92137   1.445  0.14856   
DA6           -0.53457    0.17292 4107.87271  -3.091  0.00200 **
DA7            0.14692    0.05214 3851.36370   2.818  0.00486 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

---

**Given these, what is the most accurate way to infer how well `DA` predicts speed, while controlling for word count?**

Comment: Binning word_count into quintiles and calling these random effects doesn't sound very meaningful. To make the other model comparisons you can use anova(model0, model1).

Answer (score 1):

To give an authoritative answer about the best way to model this would require some subject knowledge, because causal pathways can be complex.

But based on the information you have presented, the final option (word count in quintiles as random effect) seems obviously poor - it very rarely makes sense to treat a continuous variable as a random effect.

The most reasonable seems to be keeping both `DA` and `word_count` and their interaction in the model, i.e. `lm(formula = speed ~ DA * word_count)`. If you believed that there was no good reason to expect an interaction or had very little data to analyse, omitting the interaction could be reasonable too.

Note that even the model with the interaction explains just 2% of the variance in `speed`, which is tiny.